# Incoherent measures with perf record

Tags: linux, perf-event, perf

While trying to get some measures from HPC with `perf record`, I'm getting some incoherent values, I think.

I'm using the next command to get some mesures:

`perf record -T -F997 -e cache-misses:u,branch-misses:u find / -name afile`

As output, there are values that decrease instead of increase. Is it possible?

As an example, here are three consecutive measures:

```
...

find  6775 15876.485325: branch-misses:u:     413ff0 [unknown] (/usr/bin/find)

find  6775 15876.501636: branch-misses:u:     403d8c [unknown] (/usr/bin/find)

find  6775 15876.536531: branch-misses:u:     4140a0 [unknown] (/usr/bin/find)

...
```

The second measure is lower than the first one. How is it possible that branch-misses decrease? Am I misinterpreting the output?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Are you looking at the value next to `[unknown}`

Comment: Hi Miline. Yes I'm looking at the hex values before [unknown].

Comment: Aren't  those the symbol addresses of binary? isnt `15876.485325` the outpu?

Comment: I think 15876.485325 is the timestamp. isn't it?

Comment: Since this value never changes, I think it's the PID.

Comment: How are you getting the outpu? by `perf report`?

Comment: Im' using perf script:
perf script -i perf.data

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I wonder where the values are :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using `perf script` which gives trace of perf record or List all raw events from perf record. Try doing `perf report` to see the perf output numbers

Refer http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

Comment: I can not see the values with perf report either. I think like they are not being saved.

Comment: Also tried with:

perf script -f time,event,trace -i perf.data

And I get:

15854.088543: cache-misses:u: 

15854.088547: cache-misses:u: 

15854.088553: branch-misses:u: 

15854.088554: cache-misses:u:

...

So it seems that the measures are not being saved.

Comment: if you can see perf script.. you should be able to see perf report.. run perf record for longer time

Comment: Yes, perf report works, but it only shows percentages. Perhaps I'm not using the right tool. What I'm looking for is for a list of events values in the form:


Timestamp, event, value of the counter.


Perf seems to output the data summarized, not like a list of events. Am I wrong?